# rabbitmq list queues on all vhosts

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I've got rabbitmq with couple virtual hosts, there is few queues on each.
How can I list all queues from all vhosts using rabbitmqctl?
I've tried:

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues -p /*
rabbitmqctl list_queues -p *
rabbitmqctl list_queues -p /
rabbitmqctl list_queues -p ./*
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
ordered_vhosts=$(./rabbitmqctl list_vhosts -q | xargs -n1 | sort -u)

for V in $ordered_vhosts; do
    echo "*****Vhost $V Total queues " $(./rabbitmqctl list_queues -q -p $V | wc -l)
    for Q in $(./rabbitmqctl list_queues -q name messages -p $V | xargs -n2 | sort -u); do
        echo "Vhost $V queue-name total-messages $Q"
    done
done
```

Comment: With a few modifications this works beautifully! Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest an option with few modifications, since the code above doesn't work as is:


```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
ordered_vhosts=$(rabbitmqctl list_vhosts -q | xargs -n1 | sort -u)

for V in $ordered_vhosts; do
    echo "*****Vhost $V Total queues " $(rabbitmqctl list_queues -q -p $V | wc -l)
    for Q in $(rabbitmqctl list_queues -q name messages -p $V | xargs -n2 | sort -u); do
        echo "Vhost $V queue-name total-messages $Q"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `for i in $(rabbitmqctl list_vhosts); do echo vhost: $i && rabbitmqctl list_queues -p $i; done` to just run from the command line

Answer (score 3):

It works for me

```
rabbitmqctl list_vhosts | xargs -n1  rabbitmqctl list_queues -p
```